# Split a text by quotes but not spaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I split a given text by quotes only? For example:

```
'He said "This is true", then added "Lets go"'
```

would be split like:

```
['He said', '"This is true"', ', then added', '"Lets go"']
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I think you're looking for the split method: str='Some string with "double quotes".'
str.split('\"')
I'm using \" to make sure " is interpreted as char

Comment: @messerbill I managed to match them using this regex: `test.match(/(?<=^"| ").*?(?=" |"$)/g)` but i cant split it this way

Comment: Warning, you wont catch the double quotes in the array using the split function

Comment: `str.match(/"[^"]+"|[^"]+/g)`

Comment: @H. Figueiredo Thats still ok.

Comment: @anubhava That seems correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `match` with alternation based regex:

```js
const str = 'He said "This is true", then added "Lets go"'

var arr = str.match(/"[^"]*"|[^"]+/g);

console.log(arr);
```

Regex has 2 alternatives:

- `"[^"]*"`: Match quotes strings
- `|`: OR
- `[^"]+`: Match 1+ non-double-quote characters

Answer (score 0):

```
    var text = 'He said "This is true", then added "Lets go"';
    var indexes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] === '"') indexes.push(i);
    }
    var array = [];
    array.push(text.substring(0, indexes[0] + 1));
    for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        array.push(text.substring(indexes[i], indexes[i + 1]));
    }
```